# TASM accessing double word's higher and lower word while using only 16-bit registers

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

My question is how can I write or read sth to/from higher or lower word of double word variable when I can use only 16 bit registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read/write to the appropriate locations in memory. The low word is at `[address]`, while the high word is at `[address+2]`.

For example, if `SI` holds the address of the double-word in memory, then this will read the low word into `AX` and the high word into `DX`:

```
mov ax, [si]
mov dx, [si+2]
```